# Cannot set MAC address for Pi Zero W USB ethernet gadget

Tags: ssh, config.txt, cmdline.txt

I am trying to create a portable debian system that runs on pi zero w using the 0W image from [debian-downloads](https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/), I downloaded the image and flashed it to an sd card using etcher.io, next I edited `cmdline.txt` to look like this

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200 root=LABEL=RASPIROOT rw fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 cma=64M rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_ether  g_ether.dev_addr=00:22:82:ff:ff:22
```

then edited `config.txt` to look like this

```
enable_uart=1
upstream_kernel=1

kernel=vmlinuz-5.15.0-2-rpi
# For details on the initramfs directive, see
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=10532
initramfs initrd.img-5.15.0-2-rpi
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

after ejecting the sd card and booting the pi with usb from the computer I get and interface called `usb0` but has a different mac address than the one i defined

I found this [link](https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?f=29&t=171791&p=1099804#p1099804) that mentions `dev_addr` and `host_addr` but it wasn't helpful

Comment: a link from your link states *`g_ether.host_addr lets you assign the MAC address visible to the host PC`* ... so, I think you need to set the `g_ether.host_addr`

Comment: @JaromandaX I did try including `g_ether.host_addr` as stated in the link but still i get a complete random address that does not match the one i used